# Некорректно срабатывает регулярное выражение на повторный submit

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть регулярка

```
^([a-z0-9_\.-]+)@([а-яa-z0-9\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})$
```

Я заполняю форму и намерено оставляю пустым одно из обязательных полей, жму отправить. Как и запланировано выдает ошибку что поле допустим `Login` пустое. Я вписываю логин и снова жму отправить и тут выдает ошибку, что email неверный, жму отправить снова, ошибка пропадает, жму снова отправить, ошибка на неверный email снова появляется (при этом все поля заполнены верно). Короче говоря, если сабмитить форму 50 раз подряд, то ошибка будет выскакивать через раз. С другой стороны, если страничку просто обновлять, то ошибки нет. В сценарии траблов нет, регуляркой проверяются еще несколько полей, но сдвиг именно на мыле? В чём может быть причина?

Comment: Причина может быть в другом месте кода. Например, если вы пытаетесь устанавливать/снимать значение в сессии.

Comment: Сессии пока не используются.

Comment: Учитесь дебажить свой код.
В сообщение об ошибке добавьте еще и мыло. что бы было видно какое оно (вдруг оно вообще не передается, или передается не правильно) и видя email можно будет сделать вывод, либо не правильно работает регулярка либо не правильно передается емейл...

Comment: Досмотрел только что, переменную не ту передавал...) Мозг скриптом не исправишь ©

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как минимум, минус разместите вначале символьного класса. Так правильнее.

Comment: knes зачот) Теперь все ок. Спасибо!